# Incorrect DateTime format

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I wrote code that could read the date in format `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM`, but now I need it to read date in the format if `mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm Am/PM`.

Can someone please guide me in right direction?

My code:

```
IFormatProvider culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR", true);

foreach (FileInfo fi in fiArray)
{
    try
    {
        StreamReader reader = fi.OpenText();

        string date;
        string logContent = reader.ReadLine();

        string patternDate = "(?<logDate>(\\d){2}-(\\d{2})-(\\d{4})\\s(\\d{2}):(\\d{2})\\s?(?i)(am|pm))";

        Regex reg = new Regex(patternDate);
        date = reg.Match(logContent).Value.ToString();

        // for dt2, the error happens here
        DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(date, culture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
        //  DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(date, format, provider);

        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Regex reg1 = new Regex("^(ARCH(?!9{2}))");

            bool flag = reg1.IsMatch(line);

            if (flag == true)
            {
               string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyymmddHHMMss");
               string[] values = line.Split(',').Select(sValue => sValue.Trim()).ToArray();
               //  string uniqueGuid = SequentialGuidGenerator.NewGuid().ToString();

               string uniqueGuid = Utility.generateID();
               uniqueGuid = uniqueGuid.Replace("-", "").Substring(0,18);
               string RPT_ID = values[0].ToString();
               RPT_ID = RPT_ID.Remove(0, 4);

               table.Rows.Add(uniqueGuid, RPT_ID, values[1].ToString(), dt2);
           }
           else
           { }
       }

       reader.Close();
   }
   catch (MyException e)
   {
       throw e.MyExceptiona(e, fi);
   }
}

Utility.InsertData(table);
```

This code is reading  `01-02-2016 12:40 AM` but I need it to read  `01-15-2016 12:40 AM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
DateTime parsedDate ;
string YourDate = "01-15-2016 12:40 AM";
string pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm tt";
DateTime.TryParseExact(YourDate, pattern, null,
                               DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

how about :

```
DateTime mydt;
DateTime.TryParseExact("01-16-2016 12:40 AM", "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out mydt)
```

For reference about custome datetime parsing : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks but it is returning"{1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM} for all input values .